# Commitizen with 4 number versions?

Tags: python, versioning, commitizen

**Is it possible to use [commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen) to automatically bump a version format like this: `vX.Y.Z.&` (eg. `v2.23.3.9`)?**

It is used as `vX.` + semver, essentially a "major-major" version on top (here `v2`), for business needs. It is never updated unless for marketing/business needs.

I have been looking into the `commitizen.customize` system, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Ideally I would like to be able to simply do something like `cz bump` and have it create a new version (with changelog and the whole thing) based on conventional commits, but not ever change the top-version.